# How to add an external project to Xcode 4?

Tags: ios4, xcode4

I am stuck with an issue of including an project in Xcode 4. I have all the document but it works with Xcode 3 and not Xcode 4.

How to add `ZXingWidget.xcodeproj` to my project in Xcode 4?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Xcode 4, you're mostly meant to create a new *Workspace* to which you can add multiple projects. From the main menu: File > New... > New Workspace...

Once you create your new workspace, drag the Xcode project files into the project navigator of the newly-created workspace. Drop the first one anywhere in the project navigator pane but be careful to note the insertion pointer when you drop the second one. Advice: Drop it beneath the entire first project but with your pointer as close to the left edge of the project navigator panel as you can get. This makes sure you're not inserting a project into another project.

In this way, you get all the benefits of a workspace (automatic dependencies, etc.) without changing the structure of the projects themselves. Then you simply open the workspace rather than the individual projects within it.

Comment: Can you add multiple projects without using workspace? because it slows down my XCode when im using workspace

Answer (score 1):

Despite that this question had been asked months ago, here is a [great resource](http://yannickloriot.com/2011/04/how-to-install-zxing-in-xcode-4/) directly answering it. It worked flawlessly for me (even though I had ARC turned on for the main project I was importing it into).

Comment: I am having a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701780/using-non-arc-code-in-an-arc-enabled-project-adding-facebook . I need to add a non-arc files to a arc project. Based on your answer it seems like you have added non-arc files to a arc project, so how did you do this ?

Comment: I added an external non-ARC project to my ARC project using the steps described in the resource linked above and it seems to have worked. One trick is I needed to search for "All" build settings (not "Basic") for the "Header Search Paths" option to show up.