# Using Non-ARC Code in an ARC-Enabled Project - Adding Facebook

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, twitter, automatic-ref-counting

When i created my project, i made it to support `ARC`, so my project will support iOS 4.3 and above.

Now i need to integrate Twitter and Facebook to it. Both Facebook and Twitter frameworks given by the companies does not support `ARC`.

Most of the files have dealloc, and released its variables. Some say to scrap the project and redo it disabling ARC. But, i can't afford to do this, since i have done most of the stuff.

I added the `FBConnect` files (there were 4 of them) and added `-fno-objc-arc` as described in [this tutorial](http://www.jameskelso.com/post/11878189130/using-non-arc-code-in-an-arc-enabled-project). Still i get

```
file://localhost/Users/illepmorgan/Documents/Projects/illep/untitled%20folder/alphaproject/alphaproject/FBRequest.m: error: Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Existing ivar '_delegate' for unsafe_unretained property 'delegate' must be __unsafe_unretained
```

I need help, i can't redo this again.

Comment: Are you sure you followed the guide correctly? Double check that you have added the flag to all of the files.

Comment: Yes i did. I tried it all over again. and i get that message which i have added above.

Comment: Does any one know how to solve this ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Make sure that you added the -fno-objc-arc flag to each implementation file (.m file).

And then clean the project  (Project menu -> clean) and build again. I have sometimes had to clean and build twice when doing this in class. Seems like a little bug.

Comment: You will also have to add the JSON files (which are in a folder). So do i have to add the flag for those files as well ? The JSON files were not identified in the `target` to add the flag. What should i do now ?

Comment: JSON files are not objective-c code, and you won't compile them, so this flag doesn't apply.

Comment: well, `FBConnect` the Facebook framework has a `JSON` folder and when you look in that you will find a lot of `Objective-C` code. So do i have to `flag` them too ?

Comment: Yes, any objective-c implementation files (.m), regardless of folder.

Answer (score 3):

there is actually a much easy way working in mixed ARC and Facebook none ARC .
see my post on how to use it 
http://nabtech.wordpress.com/2012/02/02/facebook-ios-sdk-and-arc/