# when release objects in objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management

I am confused in some condition when I have to release an object? So I wants to know when we release objects in objective C. Can I use autorelease where I alloc the objects  any disadvantage of autorelease?  Where release the following objects?

Case 1:

```
SelectFrame *obj=[[SelectFrame alloc]initWithNibName:@"SelectFrame" bundle:nil];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
```

Case 2:

```
UIView *barView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 500, 200,50)];
barView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:barView];
```

Case 3:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                         [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to release for the Above two cases.

**Case 1:**

```
SelectFrame *obj=[[SelectFrame alloc]initWithNibName:@"SelectFrame" bundle:nil];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
[obj release];
```

**Case 2:**

```
UIView *barView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 500, 200,50)];
barView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:barView];
[barView release];
```

**Case 3:**

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                     [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

You don't need a release here, as the request object is in autoreleased mode.

**Remember two things.**

1.) You have to manually release an object when you `retain` or `alloc-init` that object.

2.) Class methods which do not have alloc methods return an `autoreleased` object hence you don't need to release those objects.

**Disadvantage of using `autorelease` :**

Ok, so what does `autorelease` mean? Autorelease means , not us, but our App would decide when to release the object. Supposing case 2 of your question. After `barView` is added to `self.view` there is no need of this allocated object. Hence, we release it. But, if we had kept it in `autorelease` mode, the App would keep it for longer time, wasting some part of memory by still keeping that object. Hence, we shouldn't use autorelease here.

**Advantage of using `autorelease` :**

This over-popular example.

```
- (NSString*) getText
{
    NSString* myText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello"];
    return myText;
}
```

Here, the 3rd line causes a leak because we do not release the memory allocated to `myText`.
Hence,

```
- (NSString*) getText
{
    NSString* myText = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello"] autorelease];
    return myText;
}
```

**SOLUTION**

Use ARC, forget `retain` `release` :)

Comment: thanks for Answer, I have one more issue, I am using JSON and few objects shows memory leak in JSON sdk .m files? and When i enable ARC then these file shows me error. What to do for using JSON sdk with ARC

Comment: I don't know much about what code you are using. But you could google up something like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701780/using-non-arc-code-in-an-arc-enabled-project-adding-facebook

Answer (score 1):

If using **ARC** in 3 cases then **no need to release** anything just use wisely (alloc if needed)

If not using ARC then its needed to release

Now case 1 :

```
SelectFrame *obj=[[SelectFrame alloc]initWithNibName:@"SelectFrame" bundle:nil];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
[obj release];
```

Case 2:

```
UIView *barView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 500, 200,50)];
barView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:barView];
[barView release];
```

Case 3:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                     [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]];
[[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self] autorelease];
```

Refere [How-to-avoid-memory-leaks-in-iPhone-applications](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/107800/How-to-avoid-memory-leaks-in-iPhone-applications) link.