# Why I'm receiving an error when I'm using multiple third party code along with my own code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

The third party code I'm using had been written without using ARC, but I've created my own project using ARC, while running the program I'm getting error. How can I use a code that has been written without using ARC along with the code that has been written using ARC? Please advise me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Non-ARC Code in an ARC-Enabled Project - Adding Facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701780/using-non-arc-code-in-an-arc-enabled-project-adding-facebook)

Comment: Yes I've used the -fno-objc-arc, but still getting error

Comment: You did not even write what kind of error you are getting, how we could guess what is wrong. If 3rd party code is working ok -fno-objc-arc flag should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're adding a class that do not implement the ARC then you need go build phases and add the flag  -fno-objc-arc to the class(.m file) file which is not implementing ARC

Make sure that you added the -fno-objc-arc flag to each implementation file (.m file).

And then clean the project (Project menu -> clean) and build again. I have sometimes had to clean and build twice when doing this in class. Seems like a little bug