# iOS: OCCalendar undefined symbols error

Tags: ios

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OCCalendarViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TestCalenderController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Usually i get this error when i've imported a `.m`, however my imports are correct.
I've stuck quite close to the demo project that is [included on the git page](https://github.com/ocrickard/OCCalendar).

The only thing that i know to be different is that i'm using ARC, whereas the demo appears to be handling references itself. To the best of my ability, i've "coverted" the code to be ARC freindly, mainly removing release statements. This is the only error that appears within xcode so i'm not sure where to go from here.

It should be noted that i'm not expecting a huge amount of feedback from this as its 3rd party code issue, but if anyone could help or suggest anything, it'll be most apperciated

Comment: If you have downloaded this third party tool then you should see their pull requests from where you have downloaded the project.

Comment: You are missing some framework as the error suggests. Please check in the demo code and check which one is missing. That should do the trick for you.

Comment: Did you try removing the release statements manually? You could have set a compiler flag to make the non-ARC code compatible with your ARC code? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701780/using-non-arc-code-in-an-arc-enabled-project-adding-facebook

Comment: urgh, this is testing me.
I've included all missing frameworks, i've gone through & removed where all releases are made. i've double checked the headers three times.